# IE does not retain deleted DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I am taking a dom element in a variable and then erasing it. When I append that variable to the dom at some other place it does not appear in all versions of IE. Whereas it works fine in chrome and FF

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NdtNP/

HTML:

```
<div id="d1" style="color:red">sdjkfk
    <a href="google.com">Click here</a>
    sjlfkj df
</div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var a = $("#d1").children("a");
    $("#d1").html("");
    $("#d2").append(a);
});
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What versions of IE reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bYjQx/)***

You should use `remove`. It will return the elements.

```
$(function(){
 var a = $("#d1").children("a").remove();
 $("#d1").html("");
 $("#d2").append(a);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**.detach()**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```
$(function () {
    var a = $("#d1").children("a").detach();
    $("#d1").html("");
    $("#d2").append(a);
});
```

[***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NdtNP/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to append before deleting by switching up your script like this

```
$(function(){
    var a = $("#d1").children("a");
    $("#d2").append(a);
    $("#d1").html("");
});
```

Comment: I cannot do that in my project. I just simplified my question here. Anyways thanks.